# Remove extra content from value lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list which following list is a part of my list:

```
PrtayStetaten2
155,198,293
NrteintenertdoDrtS
154,945,128
GartmertBertoy
119,227,195
PtylytayStytatn3
84,222,289
Xbttyryox36
X84,138,759
etghrth
345
hrhyjuj
0
tytyjhfdff
opop0
2018 Q3
```

Now i want to remove extra content from value lines only like following:

```
PrtayStetaten2
155,198,293
NrteintenertdoDrtS
154,945,128
GartmertBertoy
119,227,195
PtylytayStytatn3
84,222,289
Xbttyryox36
84,138,759
etghrth
345
hrhyjuj
0
tytyjhfdff
0
2018 Q3
```

I can't use following regex because it remove content from non-value lines like `2018 Q3` and `PrtayStetaten2`

```
find: ^.*?(?<!\d)(?<!\d,)(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?!,?\d).*

replace:  $1
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: @Mark not working!

Comment: What are the rules to delete “extra content”?

Comment: @Toto from what I understand, the first lines are alphanumerics or alphanumerics + digits, and the second lines should be digits

Comment: @Mark: Yes, probably but it should have been given in the question. What to do with lines like `123blah123` or `blah123blah`?

Comment: @Toto  you're not wrong! indeed, I was just noting a pattern. The options are: 1. ask, wait for OP to clarify, or 2. write an answer, then wait for OP to tell you your answer is wrong. But truly, OP is wrong, because a question that can be answered many ways is a bad question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
^(\D.*\R+)\D+
```

which matches a complete line starting with a non-digit, followed by some non-digit characters at the beginning of the next line; and replace it with

```
\1
```

which will remove the non-digit characters at the start of the second line.

Note:

- ". matches newline" must not be checked
- on unix machines you can replace `\R+` with `\n`.

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tzIUpI/1)